# libxml for python's utf encoding issue or mine?

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, libxml2

hi all I'm trying to extract the "META" description from a webpage using libxml for python. When it encounters UTF chars it seems to choke and display garbage chars. However when getting the data via a regex I get the unicode chars just fine. Am I doing something wrong with libxml?

thanks

```
''' test encoding issues with utf8 '''

from lxml.html import fromstring
from lxml.html.clean import Cleaner
import urllib2
import re

url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LE-JN7_rxtE'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()


xmldoc = fromstring(page)
desc = xmldoc.xpath('/html/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content')
meta_description = desc[0].strip()

print "**** LIBXML TEST ****\n" 
print meta_description


print "**** REGEX TEST ******"
reg = re.compile(r'<meta name="description" content="(.*)">')
for desc in reg.findall(page):
  print desc
```

OUTPUTS:

```
**** LIBXML TEST ****

My name is Hikakin.<br>I'm Japanese Beatboxer.<br><br>HIKAKIN Official Blog<br>http://ameblo.jp/hikakin/<br><br>ãã³çã³ãã¥<br>http://com.nicovideo.jp/community/co313576<br><br>â»å¾¡ç¨ã®æ¹ã¯Youtubeã®ã¡ãã»ã¼ã¸ã¾ã...
**** REGEX TEST ******
My name is Hikakin.&lt;br&gt;I'm Japanese Beatboxer.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;HIKAKIN Official Blog&lt;br&gt;http://ameblo.jp/hikakin/&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;ニコ生コミュ&lt;br&gt;http://com.nicovideo.jp/community/co313576&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;※御用の方はYoutubeのメッセージまた...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
xmldoc = fromstring(page.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that the problem is that your console does not support the display of Unicode characters. Try piping the output to a file and then open it in something that can display Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

In lxml, you need to pass the encoding to the parser.
For HTML/XML parsing:

```
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + wiki_word
parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')  # you can either use an XMLParser()

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
doc = etree.parse(page, parser)
T = doc.xpath('//p//text()')
text = u''.join(T).encode('utf-8')
```